# JWT implementation in Crystal

Tags: jwt, crystal

I'm trying to learn Crystal. I made this to create a web token for authorization. I keep it updated on [GitHub](https://github.com/twharmon/cwt).

Here is how I use it:

```
user = {
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    role: "user",
}

token = CWT.make(user)
# CWT.revoke(token)

begin
    # new_token is not nil if token was "stale", > 1 day old
    payload, new_token = CWT.get_payload(token)
    puts payload
    if new_token != nil
        puts new_token
    end
rescue ex
    puts ex.message # expired, invalid, etc.
end
```

Here is the source:

```
require "base64"
require "crypto/subtle"
require "openssl/hmac"


class CWT
    @@secret = ENV["CWT_SECRET"]
    @@life_span = Time::Span.new(24*3, 0, 0)
    @@stale_span = Time::Span.new(24, 0, 0)
    @@revoked_tokens = [] of String

    def self.make(payload) : String
        expires_payload = "#{Base64.strict_encode(Time.now.to_s)}.#{Base64.strict_encode(payload.to_json)}"

        return "#{expires_payload}.#{hmac(@@secret, expires_payload)}"
    end

    def self.get_payload(token : String) : {JSON::Any, String?}
        if token.split(".").size != 3
            raise "token not properly formatted"
        end

        if is_expired(token)
            raise "token expired"
        end

        if has_integrity(token) != true
            raise "token doesn't haave integrity"
        end

        if is_revoked(token)
            raise "token has been revoked"
        end

        payload_json = Base64.decode_string(token.split(".")[1])

        if is_stale(token)
            new_token = make(payload_json)
        end

        return JSON.parse(payload_json), new_token
    end

    def self.revoke(token : String) : Void
        @@revoked_tokens.push(token)
    end

    def self.is_revoked(token : String) : Bool
        if @@revoked_tokens.index(token) != nil
            spawn do
                @@revoked_tokens.delete(token)
                @@revoked_tokens.each do |revoked_token|
                    if is_expired(revoked_token)
                        @@revoked_tokens.delete(revoked_token)
                    end
                end
            end

            return true
        end

        return false
    end

    def self.is_expired(token : String) : Bool
        expires_str= Base64.decode_string(token.split(".")[0])
        made_at = Time.parse(expires_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")

        return made_at + @@life_span < Time.now
    end

    def self.is_stale(token : String) : Bool
        expires_str= Base64.decode_string(token.split(".")[0])
        made_at = Time.parse(expires_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")

        return made_at + @@stale_span < Time.now
    end

    def self.has_integrity(token : String) : Bool
        parts = token.split(".")
        expires_payload = "#{parts[0]}.#{parts[1]}"

        return Crypto::Subtle.constant_time_compare(hmac(@@secret, expires_payload), parts[2])
    end

    def self.hmac(key : String, data : String) : String
        return Base64.strict_encode(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(:sha256, key, data))
    end
end
```

1. Do you see any potential bugs / crashes?
2. How can I improve the performance of this?
3. How can I improve the security of this?